# How to call << operator on object in array?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

I have an array of pointers to objects

```
Room *rooms[MAX_ROOMS];

rooms[0] = new Room(101, 1, RT_CLASSIC, 200.00);
rooms[1] = new Room(102, 2, RT_CLASSIC, 280.00);
rooms[2] = new Room(103, 4, RT_FAMILY_SUITE, 360.00);
```

Class **Room** has an overloaded friend operator <<:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Room &room) {
    return out << room.toString();
}
```

How do I output **rooms** array like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num_of_rooms; i++) {
    cout << rooms[i] << "\n";
}
```

Because now it outputs addresses to **Room** objects. I need it to call my **Room** << operator.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Why pointers and why `new`... this is painful code.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Because I use function CreateRoom() for creating rooms which adds a new room to rooms array therefore I must use new

Comment: Hmm... I don't think that's a real argument, but that's off topic. No worries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so:

```
cout << *(rooms[i]) << "\n";
```

`rooms[i]` returns a pointer to a `Room`, that's why `cout` is printing the address. To get the object itself, you have to dereference it (like above).